# If statement only execute once

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, I have an if statement like which refresh the section if the url# is equal to #Data-1

```
var Panelchecker = location.hash;
if (Panelchecker !== "#Data-1") {
    window.setTimeout(function(){
         location.reload();
    },1000);
}
```

this causes an infinite loop, how do i fix it?

P.S: I do not want to make a checker

```
var Panelchecker = location.hash;
var checker = "1";
if (Panelchecker !== "#Data-1") {
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        location.reload();
        checker="0";
    },1000);
}
```

I don't want the above approach

Comment: Can i use break here?

Comment: `location.href=location.href.split('#')[0];`

Comment: why are you using window.setTimeout ? it causes here to load every 1000 ms.

Comment: You're not refreshing the section, but the whole page.

Comment: the setTimeout() is for special usage in my actual application, and yes the whole page

Comment: @anson920520 You should consider writing "checker" to cookies. Otherwise it's a design issue.

Comment: You're going to have to elaborate, you haven't told us how the url would change.  The refresh itself won't change the hash, so it looks very much by design atm.

Comment: yes, i will update it now, in more details

Comment: But actually location.href=location.href.split('#')[0]; solve my issues

Answer (score 0):

You should change the location, not reload it, because you'll still have that hash in the URL which will force another refresh, and another, and another...

There are many ways to do it, for example this will remove the hash from the URL:

```
location = location.pathname;
```

Btw. your code is set to refresh the page only if the hash **is not** `#Data-1`, yet you said `"which refresh the section if the url# is equal to #Data-1"`.

Btw2. that checker thing in your code won't do anything as it dies as soon as the refresh happens.

Answer (score -1):

First of all You wanted to refresh page if `url# is equal to #Data-1`. So `===` should be used instead of `!==`.

next,

> this causes an infinite loop

because `location.reload();` doesn't remove the hash part of the url. There for `Panelchecker === "#Data-1"` becomes true every time page refresh.

Another thing is using `window.setTimeout()` method is useless because page is reloading.

So this will solve your problem

```
 var Panelchecker = location.hash;    
 if (Panelchecker === "#Data-1") {  
     window.location.href = location.pathname;
 }
```